# How to add padding between chips and change the background color of close button

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

[image: Add padding between chips]

Could someone please help with adding padding between the chips so they're not touching one another and removing the background color of the 'x'.

Here is the .css

```
        .chip{
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0 25px;
            padding-bottom: 25px;
            height: 30px;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 30px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        img{
            float: right !important;
            background-color: #f1f1f1 !important;
        }
    }

    <div>
      <ion-label>Activities</ion-label>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="addActivities" (keyup.enter)="addActivity()" 
              placeholder="Enter activity">
</div>
    <div class="chip" *ngFor="let activity of activities">
          <label> {{ activity }} </label>
          <button (click)="deleteActivity(activity)">
            <img src="assets/img/ic-small-close.png"/>
          </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use margin in `chip` class within `.scss` file.

You can set `margin: 5px` or just right margin `margin-right: 5px`. It would work.

```css
.chip{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 25px;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 30px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        margin: 5px;
}
.chip img{
    float: right !important;
    background-color: #f1f1f1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="chip">
  <label>Activity 1</label>
  <button (click)="deleteActivity(activity)">
      <img src="assets/img/ic-small-close.png"/>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="chip">
  <label>Activity 2</label>
  <button (click)="deleteActivity(activity)">
      <img src="assets/img/ic-small-close.png"/>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based off what I see you might be able to get the border style you want by adding margins

```
   .chip{
                display: inline-block;
                margin-left: 20px;
                margin-right: 20px;
                padding: 0 25px;
                padding-bottom: 25px;
                height: 30px;
                font-size: 12px;
                line-height: 30px;
                border-radius: 25px;
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply margins for your `.chip` class.

see: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

To change color of your close button you should apply the rule on `button`, not on the image (img), see below:

```
.chip button{
    float: right !important;
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

```css
.chip{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 0 2px; /* margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px; */
}
.chip button{
    float: right !important;
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <ion-label>Activities</ion-label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter activity">
  </div>
  
    <div class="chip" >
          <label> chip 01 </label>
          <button>
            x
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="chip" >
          <label> chip 02 </label>
          <button>
            x
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="chip" >
          <label> chip 03 </label>
          <button>
            x
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="chip" >
          <label> chip 04 </label>
          <button>
            x
          </button>
    </div>
```